# Cannot identify source of "Type Mismatch" Error

Tags: excel, vba

The following macro gives a type mismatch error when run, and I cannot see where there is one. I would appreciate any advice on this issue:

```
Sub Add_W()
Dim cel As Range
Dim selectedRange As Range
Dim WCount As Integer

Set selectedRange = ("C4:C20")

Set WCount = 0

For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
    Wname = cel.Text

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = Wname + " Table"
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = Wname + " Plots"
    End With

    Sheets(Wname + " Table").Select

    Sheets("Report").Select
    If IsEmpty(Range("B5")) Then
        Rows(5).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
    End If
    Range("B5") = Wname
    WCount = WCount + 1

    Sheets("Input").Select
    Range("U" & WCount + 1) = Wname

    Sheets(Wname + " Plots").Select
Next cel


End Sub
```

Comment: `Set selectedRange = ("C4:C20")` is trying to assign a `String` to a `Range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Set selectedRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C20")`.